# Spring - parse payload from http request as array

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am new to spring rest api, i need to parse payload from post,put and delete required as array or any other objects so that it can be commonly accessible across the application.

If any example or tutorials available please share it.

Comment: `DELETE` requests can't have bodies or payload.

Comment: And add more details on what exactly you want